# How to compose data in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, foreach

I have query that returns items from db. What i want to do is that ItemTypeTarget has as child ItemTarget.. I've already got this result, but problem is because I also i want to have ItemVariationTargets as child of ItemTarget. This is where i stuck.
My code so far:

```
$curGroup = array(
        "Name" => "",
        "ID" => null,
        "ItemTarget" => array()
    );

    $lastItem = array(
        "Name" => "",
        "ID" => null
    );

    foreach($items as $key => $item){
        if($curGroup["ID"] != $item["ItemTypeID"]){     
            if(count($curGroup["ItemTarget"]) > 0){
                $jsonArr["ItemTypeTarget"][] = $curGroup;

            }
            $curGroup = array(
                "Name" => $item["tName"],
                "ID" => $item["ItemTypeID"],
                "ItemTarget" => array()
            );
        }

        $curGroup["ItemTarget"][] = array(
            "ID" => $item["ItemID"],
            "Name" => $item["ItemName"],
            "ItemVariationTarget" => array()
        );          

        if($lastItem["ID"]!=$item["iID"]){
            $lastItem[] = array(
                "ID" => $item["iID"],
                "Name" => $item["iName"]    
            );
        }           
    }

    if(count($curGroup["ItemTarget"]) > 0){
        $jsonArr["ItemTypeTarget"][] = $curGroup;
    }
```

My expected result should looks like:

```
    "ItemTypeTarget":[
         {
            "Name":"Noodles",
            "ID":2328,
            "ItemTarget":[
               {
                  "ID":296,
                  "Name":"Noodles basic",
                  "ItemVariationTarget":[
                  {
                     "ID":222,
                     "Name" : "Noodles chili"
                  },
                  {
                     "ID":223,
                     "Name" : "Noodles hot"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "ID":333,
                  "Name":"Tofu basic",
                  "ItemVariationTarget":[
                  {
                     "ID":334,
                     "Name" : "Tofu chili"
                  },
                  {
                     "ID":335,
                     "Name" : "Tofu hot"
                  }
               }
               ]
             }  
            ]
```

So question is.. how could i achieve this with? I try to do it thru lastItem variable, but no luck.
My data:

```
array(126) { [0]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(518) ["iName"]=> string(29) "Porce nudle čínské s masem" ["ItemID"]=> int(296) ["ItemName"]=> string(23) "nudle čínské s masem" ["tName"]=> string(2) "52" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2328) } [1]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30051) ["iName"]=> string(10) " 1 zajdsda" ["ItemID"]=> int(21896) ["ItemName"]=> string(9) "1 zajdsda" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [2]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30052) ["iName"]=> string(16) " 2 jsandk jsanjd" ["ItemID"]=> int(21897) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "2 jsandk jsanjd" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [3]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30053) ["iName"]=> string(23) " 3. papani do bříška" ["ItemID"]=> int(21898) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "3. papani do bříška" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [4]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30054) ["iName"]=> string(23) " 4. papani do bříška" ["ItemID"]=> int(21899) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "4. papani do bříška" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [5]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30055) ["iName"]=> string(23) " 5. papani do bříška" ["ItemID"]=> int(21900) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "5. papani do bříška" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [6]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30062) ["iName"]=> string(23) " 6. papani do bříška" ["ItemID"]=> int(21903) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "6. papani do bříška" ["tName"]=> string(11) "Denní menu" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2308) } [7]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(454) ["iName"]=> string(3) "22 " ["ItemID"]=> int(236) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [8]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(455) ["iName"]=> string(3) "32 " ["ItemID"]=> int(236) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [9]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(456) ["iName"]=> string(3) "45 " ["ItemID"]=> int(236) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [10]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(8980) ["iName"]=> string(3) "55 " ["ItemID"]=> int(236) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [11]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(529) ["iName"]=> string(7) "bílé " ["ItemID"]=> int(307) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [12]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(26293) ["iName"]=> string(10) "červené " ["ItemID"]=> int(307) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [13]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(5740) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(4435) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [14]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7642) ["iName"]=> string(6) "Porce " ["ItemID"]=> int(5848) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [15]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7996) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6183) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [16]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7997) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6184) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [17]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7998) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6185) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [18]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(9166) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6862) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [19]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(9168) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6864) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [20]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(9169) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(6865) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [21]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22944) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(16305) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [22]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25733) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18683) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [23]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25734) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18684) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [24]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25735) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18685) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [25]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25736) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18686) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [26]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25737) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18687) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [27]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25738) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18688) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [28]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(25739) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(18689) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [29]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(27869) ["iName"]=> string(5) "0,7l " ["ItemID"]=> int(20343) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [30]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(27870) ["iName"]=> string(3) "1l " ["ItemID"]=> int(20344) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [31]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(27871) ["iName"]=> string(5) "1.3l " ["ItemID"]=> int(20345) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [32]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30018) ["iName"]=> string(3) "2L " ["ItemID"]=> int(20345) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [33]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(29181) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(21305) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [34]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30049) ["iName"]=> string(1) " " ["ItemID"]=> int(21894) ["ItemName"]=> string(0) "" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Vína" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(2077) } [35]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22159) ["iName"]=> string(14) "32 cm kuřecí" ["ItemID"]=> int(15745) ["ItemName"]=> string(8) "kuřecí" ["tName"]=> string(15) "Šunkové pizzy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(1913) } [36]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(23076) ["iName"]=> string(17) "45 cm pizza jumbo" ["ItemID"]=> int(16422) ["ItemName"]=> string(11) "pizza jumbo" ["tName"]=> string(15) "Šunkové pizzy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(1913) } [37]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(5735) ["iName"]=> string(13) "-10 Kč Sleva" ["ItemID"]=> int(4432) ["ItemName"]=> string(5) "Sleva" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [38]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30002) ["iName"]=> string(14) "-100 Kč Sleva" ["ItemID"]=> int(4432) ["ItemName"]=> string(5) "Sleva" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [39]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30003) ["iName"]=> string(15) "-1000 Kč Sleva" ["ItemID"]=> int(4432) ["ItemName"]=> string(5) "Sleva" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [40]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(12428) ["iName"]=> string(12) "5Kč Krabice" ["ItemID"]=> int(8805) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Krabice" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [41]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(12429) ["iName"]=> string(20) "10Kč Krabice velká" ["ItemID"]=> int(8806) ["ItemName"]=> string(14) "Krabice velká" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [42]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30042) ["iName"]=> string(13) "10Kč Dýško" ["ItemID"]=> int(21890) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Dýško" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [43]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30043) ["iName"]=> string(13) "20Kč Dýško" ["ItemID"]=> int(21890) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Dýško" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [44]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30044) ["iName"]=> string(13) "30Kč Dýško" ["ItemID"]=> int(21890) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Dýško" ["tName"]=> string(8) "Pokladna" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(573) } [45]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(535) ["iName"]=> string(25) "1 maso Burger jako kráva" ["ItemID"]=> int(308) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Burger jako kráva" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [46]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(2996) ["iName"]=> string(25) "2 masa Burger jako kráva" ["ItemID"]=> int(308) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Burger jako kráva" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [47]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(2997) ["iName"]=> string(25) "3 masa Burger jako kráva" ["ItemID"]=> int(308) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Burger jako kráva" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [48]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(3001) ["iName"]=> string(19) "Normal Cheeseburger" ["ItemID"]=> int(2074) ["ItemName"]=> string(12) "Cheeseburger" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [49]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(3002) ["iName"]=> string(19) "Double Cheeseburger" ["ItemID"]=> int(2074) ["ItemName"]=> string(12) "Cheeseburger" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [50]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(3003) ["iName"]=> string(19) "Triple Cheeseburger" ["ItemID"]=> int(2074) ["ItemName"]=> string(12) "Cheeseburger" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [51]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(12736) ["iName"]=> string(22) "Porce Burger snehulák" ["ItemID"]=> int(5179) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Burger snehulák" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [52]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(9167) ["iName"]=> string(23) "Porce 1. Burger Classic" ["ItemID"]=> int(6863) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "1. Burger Classic" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [53]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(9293) ["iName"]=> string(58) "Porce 01. Burger Markát S velice dlouhým název produktu" ["ItemID"]=> int(6920) ["ItemName"]=> string(52) "01. Burger Markát S velice dlouhým název produktu" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [54]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(16854) ["iName"]=> string(56) "XXL 01. Burger Markát S velice dlouhým název produktu" ["ItemID"]=> int(6920) ["ItemName"]=> string(52) "01. Burger Markát S velice dlouhým název produktu" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [55]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22161) ["iName"]=> string(22) "porce burger objedname" ["ItemID"]=> int(15747) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "burger objedname" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [56]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(23217) ["iName"]=> string(11) "Porce Kebab" ["ItemID"]=> int(16547) ["ItemName"]=> string(5) "Kebab" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [57]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(27486) ["iName"]=> string(22) "porce Hamburger kráva" ["ItemID"]=> int(20007) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Hamburger kráva" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Hamburgry" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(83) } [58]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(494) ["iName"]=> string(30) "Porce Smažený sýr s nudlemi" ["ItemID"]=> int(269) ["ItemName"]=> string(24) "Smažený sýr s nudlemi" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Nudle" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(82) } [59]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(465) ["iName"]=> string(19) " Bonaqua neperlivá" ["ItemID"]=> int(242) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Bonaqua neperlivá" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [60]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(466) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Bonaqua perlivá" ["ItemID"]=> int(243) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Bonaqua perlivá" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [61]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(467) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Cappy Jablečný" ["ItemID"]=> int(244) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Cappy Jablečný" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [62]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(468) ["iName"]=> string(24) " Cappy Jablečný Junior" ["ItemID"]=> int(245) ["ItemName"]=> string(23) "Cappy Jablečný Junior" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [63]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(469) ["iName"]=> string(27) " Cappy Multivitamín Junior" ["ItemID"]=> int(246) ["ItemName"]=> string(26) "Cappy Multivitamín Junior" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [64]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(470) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Cappy Jahoda Junior" ["ItemID"]=> int(247) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Cappy Jahoda Junior" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [65]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(471) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Cappy Multivitamín" ["ItemID"]=> int(248) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Cappy Multivitamín" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [66]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(472) ["iName"]=> string(16) " Cappy Pomeranč" ["ItemID"]=> int(249) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "Cappy Pomeranč" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [67]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(473) ["iName"]=> string(12) " Cappy Pulpy" ["ItemID"]=> int(250) ["ItemName"]=> string(11) "Cappy Pulpy" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [68]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(474) ["iName"]=> string(19) " Cappy Lesní plody" ["ItemID"]=> int(251) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Cappy Lesní plody" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [69]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(475) ["iName"]=> string(9) " CocaCola" ["ItemID"]=> int(252) ["ItemName"]=> string(8) "CocaCola" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [70]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(476) ["iName"]=> string(16) " CocaCola Cherry" ["ItemID"]=> int(253) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "CocaCola Cherry" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [71]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(478) ["iName"]=> string(17) " CocaCola Vanilla" ["ItemID"]=> int(255) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "CocaCola Vanilla" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [72]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(3283) ["iName"]=> string(18) "0,5L CocaCola Zero" ["ItemID"]=> int(256) ["ItemName"]=> string(13) "CocaCola Zero" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [73]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(481) ["iName"]=> string(25) " Fanta Broskev a Meruňka" ["ItemID"]=> int(258) ["ItemName"]=> string(24) "Fanta Broskev a Meruňka" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [74]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(482) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Fanta Jahoda a Kiwi" ["ItemID"]=> int(259) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Fanta Jahoda a Kiwi" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [75]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(483) ["iName"]=> string(13) " Fanta Malina" ["ItemID"]=> int(260) ["ItemName"]=> string(12) "Fanta Malina" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [76]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(484) ["iName"]=> string(16) " Fanta Pomeranč" ["ItemID"]=> int(261) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "Fanta Pomeranč" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [77]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(487) ["iName"]=> string(14) " Fanta Shokata" ["ItemID"]=> int(262) ["ItemName"]=> string(13) "Fanta Shokata" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [78]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(513) ["iName"]=> string(13) " Caffé Latte" ["ItemID"]=> int(291) ["ItemName"]=> string(12) "Caffé Latte" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [79]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(514) ["iName"]=> string(10) "0.02L Pivo" ["ItemID"]=> int(292) ["ItemName"]=> string(4) "Pivo" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [80]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(515) ["iName"]=> string(29) " Ovocný drink se šlehačkou" ["ItemID"]=> int(293) ["ItemName"]=> string(28) "Ovocný drink se šlehačkou" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [81]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(517) ["iName"]=> string(33) " Horká čokoláda se šlehačkou" ["ItemID"]=> int(295) ["ItemName"]=> string(32) "Horká čokoláda se šlehačkou" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [82]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(521) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Horký ovocný čaj" ["ItemID"]=> int(299) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Horký ovocný čaj" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [83]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(522) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Horký černý čaj" ["ItemID"]=> int(300) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Horký černý čaj" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [84]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(525) ["iName"]=> string(20) " CocaCola skleněná" ["ItemID"]=> int(303) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "CocaCola skleněná" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [85]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(526) ["iName"]=> string(20) " Nestea zelený čaj" ["ItemID"]=> int(304) ["ItemName"]=> string(19) "Nestea zelený čaj" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [86]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(527) ["iName"]=> string(24) " Nestea citrónový čaj" ["ItemID"]=> int(305) ["ItemName"]=> string(23) "Nestea citrónový čaj" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [87]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(528) ["iName"]=> string(23) " Nestea broskvový čaj" ["ItemID"]=> int(306) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "Nestea broskvový čaj" ["tName"]=> string(7) "Nápoje" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(12) } [88]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(463) ["iName"]=> string(8) " Krokety" ["ItemID"]=> int(240) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Krokety" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [89]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(464) ["iName"]=> string(9) " Hranolky" ["ItemID"]=> int(241) ["ItemName"]=> string(8) "Hranolky" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [90]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(488) ["iName"]=> string(7) " Kečup" ["ItemID"]=> int(263) ["ItemName"]=> string(6) "Kečup" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [91]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(489) ["iName"]=> string(10) " Hořčice" ["ItemID"]=> int(264) ["ItemName"]=> string(9) "Hořčice" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [92]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(496) ["iName"]=> string(18) " Vařené brambory" ["ItemID"]=> int(272) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "Vařené brambory" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [93]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(498) ["iName"]=> string(21) "porce Vařená rýže" ["ItemID"]=> int(274) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "Vařená rýže" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [94]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(501) ["iName"]=> string(19) " Bramborové placky" ["ItemID"]=> int(278) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Bramborové placky" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [95]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(509) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Salátová miska" ["ItemID"]=> int(287) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Salátová miska" ["tName"]=> string(9) "Přílohy" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(11) } [96]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(480) ["iName"]=> string(18) " Dýňový koláč" ["ItemID"]=> int(257) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "Dýňový koláč" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [97]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(490) ["iName"]=> string(42) " Kuře na paprice s bramborovými plackami" ["ItemID"]=> int(265) ["ItemName"]=> string(41) "Kuře na paprice s bramborovými plackami" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [98]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(491) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Párek s chlebem" ["ItemID"]=> int(266) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Párek s chlebem" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [99]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(492) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Kuřecí řízek" ["ItemID"]=> int(267) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Kuřecí řízek" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [100]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(495) ["iName"]=> string(18) " Vepřový řízek" ["ItemID"]=> int(270) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "Vepřový řízek" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [101]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(499) ["iName"]=> string(19) " Wafle se zmrzlinou" ["ItemID"]=> int(276) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Wafle se zmrzlinou" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [102]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(500) ["iName"]=> string(21) " Gulášová polévka" ["ItemID"]=> int(277) ["ItemName"]=> string(20) "Gulášová polévka" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [103]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(502) ["iName"]=> string(38) " Pannini se šunkou, sýrem a rajčaty" ["ItemID"]=> int(279) ["ItemName"]=> string(37) "Pannini se šunkou, sýrem a rajčaty" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [104]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(503) ["iName"]=> string(18) " Párek v rohlíku" ["ItemID"]=> int(280) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "Párek v rohlíku" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [105]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(505) ["iName"]=> string(17) " Ovocný knedlík" ["ItemID"]=> int(282) ["ItemName"]=> string(16) "Ovocný knedlík" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [106]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(507) ["iName"]=> string(8) " Qurrito" ["ItemID"]=> int(285) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "Qurrito" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [107]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(508) ["iName"]=> string(23) " Těstoviny s bolognese" ["ItemID"]=> int(286) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "Těstoviny s bolognese" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [108]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(510) ["iName"]=> string(19) " Houska šunka sýr" ["ItemID"]=> int(288) ["ItemName"]=> string(18) "Houska šunka sýr" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [109]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(511) ["iName"]=> string(16) " Kuřecí bageta" ["ItemID"]=> int(289) ["ItemName"]=> string(15) "Kuřecí bageta" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [110]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(516) ["iName"]=> string(31) " Palačinka se šunkou a sýrem" ["ItemID"]=> int(294) ["ItemName"]=> string(30) "Palačinka se šunkou a sýrem" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [111]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(519) ["iName"]=> string(25) " Palačinka s marmeládou" ["ItemID"]=> int(297) ["ItemName"]=> string(24) "Palačinka s marmeládou" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [112]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(520) ["iName"]=> string(24) " Lívance se šlehačkou" ["ItemID"]=> int(298) ["ItemName"]=> string(23) "Lívance se šlehačkou" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [113]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(524) ["iName"]=> string(41) "porce Bramborová kapsa s kuřecím masem" ["ItemID"]=> int(302) ["ItemName"]=> string(35) "Bramborová kapsa s kuřecím masem" ["tName"]=> string(6) "Jídla" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(10) } [114]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(3825) ["iName"]=> string(15) "32cm Pizza č.2" ["ItemID"]=> int(2704) ["ItemName"]=> string(10) "Pizza č.2" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [115]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7908) ["iName"]=> string(15) "50cm Pizza č.2" ["ItemID"]=> int(2704) ["ItemName"]=> string(10) "Pizza č.2" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [116]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7421) ["iName"]=> string(16) "32cm Pizza Hawai" ["ItemID"]=> int(5630) ["ItemName"]=> string(11) "Pizza Hawai" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [117]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(7422) ["iName"]=> string(16) "50cm Pizza Hawai" ["ItemID"]=> int(5630) ["ItemName"]=> string(11) "Pizza Hawai" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [118]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(12748) ["iName"]=> string(23) "45 cm Tuňáková pizza" ["ItemID"]=> int(9027) ["ItemName"]=> string(17) "Tuňáková pizza" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [119]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22157) ["iName"]=> string(16) "32 cm Margherita" ["ItemID"]=> int(15743) ["ItemName"]=> string(10) "Margherita" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [120]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22158) ["iName"]=> string(15) "32 cm objedname" ["ItemID"]=> int(15744) ["ItemName"]=> string(9) "objedname" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [121]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22160) ["iName"]=> string(20) "32 cm sýrová pizza" ["ItemID"]=> int(15746) ["ItemName"]=> string(14) "sýrová pizza" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [122]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(22162) ["iName"]=> string(13) "32 cm domací" ["ItemID"]=> int(15748) ["ItemName"]=> string(7) "domací" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [123]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30023) ["iName"]=> string(31) "120 cm Danyho Štítková Pizza" ["ItemID"]=> int(21873) ["ItemName"]=> string(24) "Danyho Štítková Pizza" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [124]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30024) ["iName"]=> string(30) "60 cm Danyho Štítková Pizza" ["ItemID"]=> int(21873) ["ItemName"]=> string(24) "Danyho Štítková Pizza" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } [125]=> array(6) { ["iID"]=> int(30030) ["iName"]=> string(29) "120 cm Krutě úžasná pizza" ["ItemID"]=> int(21879) ["ItemName"]=> string(22) "Krutě úžasná pizza" ["tName"]=> string(5) "Pizza" ["ItemTypeID"]=> int(9) } }
```

Comment: Could you show us what your input data is? we can only see your expected output.

Comment: @ikhvjs i added result of query. tName and ItemTypeID is category, ItemName+ItemID is Item and iID + iName is variation

Comment: Why don't you use give us a php array instead of an image? We don't need to type the code ourself to debug. If you want people to help, at least try to let people help you easily.

Comment: @ikhvjs sorry for that! :) I already put array with data here.

Comment: Could you please provide the data in json format or just php array which could be copied to use directly?